# newtxmath \hat{} problem in beamer

Tags: beamer

Using the `newtxmath` package with `beamer` produces wrong output for the `\hat{}` command. I don't see the problem in the `article` mode. Also, using alternative packages such as `times` cause no problems. I am using TeX Live with kile under Linux Mint 14KDE.

```
\documentclass[handout,utf8]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
$\hat{\theta}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Use `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` so that beamer doesn't change the math fonts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: That should be an answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Converting Comment To Answer]

You may use `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` or, equivalently, pass the option `[professionalfonts]` to beamer:

```
\documentclass[professionalfonts]{beamer}
```

so that the Beamer's internals do not rewrite the font schemes used.